# Error when trying to call method - Cannot be applied to ()

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Image of DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uUrX.png)

I have currently created a method for updating a book using Firestore. I am attempting to call this method in onOptionsItemSelected.

I am relatively new to Android and was always under the impression when calling this method I would call it as updateBook(Book book).

Below is my updateBook method

```
@Override
public void updateBook(Book book) {
    String chapterName = editTextChapterName.getText().toString().trim();
    String chapterInfo = editTextChapterInfo.getText().toString().trim();
    int chapterNumber = numberPickerChapterNumber.getValue();

    if (chapterName.trim().isEmpty() || chapterInfo.trim().isEmpty()) { //ensure that user has not left boxes empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please add a chapter name and the chapter information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference bookRef = db.collection("Book")
            .document();

    bookRef.update("chapterName", book.getChapterName(),
            "chapterInfo", book.getChapterInfo(),"chapterNumber", book.getChapterNumber())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(AdminUpdateActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Below is where I am trying to call my method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save_icon:
            updateBook();
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Within the updateBook parenthesis I am getting an error "Cannot be applied to ()".

I have read through other questions on here to do with this topic but have not found a solution. Can someone explain how to fix this issue and why?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Your method decleration has a parameter but your method call has no arguments.

Comment: I have added an image of my db structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you should change the following line of code:

```
DocumentReference bookRef = db.collection("Book")
        .document();
```

to

```
DocumentReference bookRef = db.collection("Book")
        .document(bookId);
```

Without passing the id of the book to the `document()` method, the Firebase SDK doesn't really know which book object you want to update. Beside that, calling `document()` method on a `DocumentReference` it only generates a new random id each time.

There is also another change is also needed. Please also remove the argument from your `updateBook()` method. Should be:

```
public void updateBook() {}
```

Without any argument.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I have since updated my project as you have stated and now my update method does not error anymore. Could you answer another question in regards to Firestore?

Comment: Good to hear that you haven't an error anymore. Yes I can answer another Firestore question but in order to follow the rules of this comunity please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Thank you! I have  marked your answer as correct. Here is my other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835912/firestore-update-not-working-correctly-is-my-issue-to-do-with-the-id